# PHP Send Custom HTTP Request

Tags: php, http, curl, request

How can I send a custom HTTP Request to a server whose URL is "http://[IP]:[Port]/"?

What I mean is that, instead of the first line being a normal GET or POST like so:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

How can this be replaced with something just like:

```
CUSTOM
Host: [IP]
```

I don't mind having to use any additional libraries if necessary such as cURL.

UPDATE:

I've tried using the following cURL code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://[IP]:[Port]/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, [Port]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "CUSTOM");

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);      

print($output);
```

But it just keeps loading for 2 minutes until it said internal error (both with and without using the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST). However, if I use a standard website such as http://google.com it'll work fine.

Also I forgot to mention, the port my server is using is 7899, is this ok? Open it in my web browser fine, but cURL doesn't seem to be able to.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php and/or http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php (look for CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST)

Comment: This may be of interest: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-request.php

Comment: Just to be pedantic: if the first line isn't "Method Request-URI HTTP-Version" then it isn't HTTP.   RFC 2616 section 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's nothing wrong with your code. If you're using a shared hosting provider, ask them to open up outbound TCP port 7899.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom HTTP request method using the http_request_method_register function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-request-method-register.php

This code needs to be run on the server that will be handling the request. If you try to use a non-standard HTTP request method on any old server, depending on the server it may ignore it, or may return an error code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not seem to be able to install http_pecl, which is needed for this function. So I will have to look for alternatives at the moment.