# check domain configuration in a server in php

Tags: php, dns

How can check if a domain name (ex. `fqdn.example`) is configurated in a server with ip `xx.xx.xx.xx`?

I have to check that the domain `fqdn.example` is correctly configured on the server with a given IP.

In php I know the `dns_get_record` function but it allows me to check only the current DNS zone, not to see if a domain is not registered yet is already configured on the server where it is to reside.

NB. For security reasons I don't want to execute shell commands from php.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with [gethostbynamel()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) if the DNS is configured:

```
<?php
$hostname = "fqdn.example";
$key = "198.51.100.100";
$ips = gethostbynamel($hostname);
if (array_search ($key, $ips) != FALSE) {
    echo ("$hostname configured at $key");
}
else {
    echo ("$hostname not configured at $key");
}
?>
```

If the domain isn't configured in DNS but you want to see if your web-server is configured, you can try sending a [HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925722/php-send-custom-http-request) of the form

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: fqdn.example
Connection: Close
```

to port 80 on that IP address. If you don't get an error, the webserver is configured correctly for that FQDN.

**Update:**

To query a custom DNS server as per your comment, use [Net_DNS](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS).

Comment: This is ok, but this only works if the domain is registered. I want to query the server with ip XXXXX and see the configuration of the DNS domain example.com (if it exists on that server)